# Python pandas reading files issue

Tags: python, pandas

Getting FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Incomeearnedreport_(26).xls' error.
Even though the files exist in path I've gave.
Here is my Code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import os

path = os.getcwd()
path = path + "/Incomeearned/"

files = os.listdir(path)
df = pd.DataFrame()
print(files)

for f in files:
    data = pd.read_excel(f, 'Report')
    df = df.append(data)
    print(f)
```

Comment: try using os.path.join()

Answer (score 0):

Try to change:

```
 data = pd.read_excel(f, 'Report')
```

with:

```
 data = pd.read_excel(os.path.join(path, f), 'Report')
```

Comment: Tried that but it gave me this error. ValueError: File is not a recognized excel file. Even though it is an xls file

Comment: @Levsha Please, check if it is in fact excel file. It can be a txt file saved with xls extension.

Comment: It is an excel file (.xls)

Comment: it's sheet name

Comment: It was originally an xml file that was as an xls extension. But I saved it as an xls file. But I tried it with other files and it did not work

Comment: Try to open them with Excel and let's see.